# Symfony 4 - global data for templates and controllers

Tags: php, symfony, templates, variables, twig

I want to make a BaseController which will gets a data for meta tags from database using Doctrine.

Example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Settings;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class BaseController extends AbstractController {  
    public function getMenu() {
    $settings = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Settings::class)
        ->findAll();

    return $settings;
}
```

I have a base template file where I put variables like

```
<meta name="description" content="{{ description }}">
<meta name="keywords" content="{{ keywords }}">
<meta name="author" content="{{ author }}">
{% block body %}

{% endblock %}
```

Then I render a page template file in PageController

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class PageController extends AbstractController {  
    public function view() {
        $content = 'blabla';
        return $this->render('pages.html.twig', ['content' => $content]);
    }
```

And for example I have a page template file where I extend base template file

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {{ content }}
{% endblock %}
```

What is the best solution for inject variables from BaseController to all controllers without hard-coding global variables in twig file?

Comment: I think you should rethink your projects structure. It makes no sense to put that logic into your baseController. It seems like something a service would do. Then you can inject your service into the controllers that need it and you'd be done. If they are static values that you want a lot then you can also think about adding them to your config.yml file and reading it from there through your bundles DependencyInjection. But using a controller this way is not the right way.

Comment: @DirkScholten I want to get that content from database so it can change. So I have to create a service container that will gets data from database, right?

Comment: Then I would consider making a service/repository that will talk to the database for you. You can then simply use auto-wiring from Symfony to inject this service into the controllers that need it and talk to the database that way. A controller shouldn't have much logic in it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a global variable, you could define a Twig function to deliver the content.

```
class ContentExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('getContent', [$this, 'getContent'])
        ];
    }

    public function getContent($name)
    {
        return "content";
    }
}
```

Don’t forget to register the Twig extension as a service in your application’s config:

```
services:
    Your\Namespace\ContentExtension:
        tags: [{ name: twig.extension }]
```

Because the Twig extension is a service, you can inject any dependecies into it, for example the Doctrine entity manager, if you want to load content from the database.

You can now use the `getContent()` function in any of your Twig templates:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {{ getContent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make it work with global `twig` variables. It is described here in the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html#referencing-services

You would create a service to pull values from the database, and make this service available to all `twig` templates via "global variable" configuration.